# Vs2015 - Copy only the project dll to output folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

Just a quick question, is there away in vs2015 to only output the compiled project dll to the output directory?

For example, my project is called `TestProject` and it reference's `EntityFramework` dll's and `MVVM Light dlls`. When I compile I only want to see `TestProject.dll` in the output folder, and no i am not talking about embedding the other dll's into the project dll.

EDIT:
Tried this in the Post-Build. Build is ok but no change on the files.

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "&{Remove-Item "$(OutDir)*" -Exclude '$(TargetFileName)'}"
```

Comment: Your project won't work without the supporting assemblies, whether side-by-side or embedded, why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can do anything you like with a post-build script, but as Stuart asks, why would you want to do this?

Comment: In my main application I am using `Prism` and a Dynamic Module loading class that loads modules from a folder. For the class library mention above, if I set the output folder to where the modules are to loaded from then main application throws exceptions when loading. If I just copy over the compiled dll, everything works fine. Also, it saves on duplicate dll's in the main project directory i.e. I don't want Prism.dll inside the main app folder and again in the Modules folder.

Comment: @DavidG how do I do this with post-build scripts?

Comment: Project properties -> Build Events -> Post build command line.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Post-Build event command line like so does what I need.

```
attrib +r "$(TargetPath)"
del /q "$(TargetDir)"
attrib -r "$(TargetPath)"
```